# A simple test case between clang++/g++/gfortran

Tags: c++, gcc, fortran, llvm, clang

I ran across this question on [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5477/485) which involves computing a sum. There, you can see a [c++](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/5487/485) and a similar [fortran](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/6831/485) implementation. Interestingly I saw the fortran version was faster by about 32%.

I thought, I was not sure about their result and tried to regenerate the situation. Here is the (very slightly) different codes I ran:

**c++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main ()
{
    const double alpha = 1;
    std::cout.precision(16);

    std::complex<double> sum = 0;
    const std::complex<double> a = std::complex<double>(1,1)/std::sqrt(2.);
    for (unsigned int k=1; k<10000000; ++k)
    {
        sum += std::pow(a, k)*std::pow(k, -alpha);

        if (k % 1000000 == 0)
            std::cout << k << ' ' << sum << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**fortran**

```
implicit none
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0.d0)
complex(dp), parameter :: i_ = (0, 1)

real(dp) :: alpha = 1
complex(dp) :: s = 0
integer :: k
do k = 1, 10000000
    s = s + ((i_+1)/sqrt(2._dp))**k * k**(-alpha)
    if (modulo(k, 1000000) == 0) print *, k, s
end do
end
```

I compile the above codes using `gcc 4.6.3` and `clang 3.0` on a `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` machine all with `-O3` flag. Here's my timings:

```
time ./a.out
```

**gfortran**

```
real    0m1.538s
user    0m1.536s
sys     0m0.000s
```

**g++**

```
real    0m2.225s
user    0m2.228s
sys     0m0.000s
```

**clang**

```
real    0m1.250s
user    0m1.244s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Interestingly I can also see that the `fortran` code is faster than the `c++` by about the same 32% when `gcc` is used. Using `clang`, however, I can see that the `c++` code actually runs faster by about 19%. Here are my questions:

1. Why is g++ generated code slower than the gfortran? Since they are from the same compiler family does this mean (this) fortran code can simply be translated into a faster code? Is this generally the case with fortran vs c++?
2. Why is `clang` doing so well here? Is there a fortran front-end for llvm compiler? If there, will the code generated by that one be even faster?

**UPDATE:**

Using `-ffast-math -O3` options generates the following results:

**gfortran**

```
real    0m1.515s
user    0m1.512s
sys     0m0.000s
```

**g++**

```
real    0m1.478s
user    0m1.476s
sys     0m0.000s
```

**clang**

```
real    0m1.253s
user    0m1.252s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Npw `g++` version is running as fast `gfortran` and still `clang` is faster than both. Adding `-fcx-fortran-rules` to the above options does not significantly change the results

Comment: Please provide compiler options used for compilation. Such options as -ffast-math for gcc may significantly affect timing.

Comment: @NikolayViskov the only flag that I explicitly use is `-O3` on all compilers.

Comment: On my machine: clang `0.62` (-ffast-math `0.60`), g++4.6 `1.23` (-ffast-math `0.78`), g++4.7 `1.19` (-ffast-math `0.76`)

Comment: Do you get the same answer from all the versions / compiler options?  Which is closer to the correct answer?   Execution speed isn't the only thing that matters...

Comment: @M.S.B. `clang` is always consistent with `g++`. Results between fortran and `g++/clang` is consistent for the first 7 floating point digits.

Comment: This is bad std::pow(k, -alpha) and probably not optimized like k**-1.

Comment: Do you really need the output?  Removing the condition and ostream output speeds it up the C++ version by a factor of ten for me, indicating the slowness is while not doing the calculation. Clang is still considerably faster than G++ even without the output, unless I use `-std=c++11` and suddenly Clang gets really slow.

Comment: I used the same `a=(i_+1._dp)/sqrt(2._dp)` under gfortran 4.8.0 and got it to run in about 1.23 seconds with the `ffast-math -O3` flags.

Comment: Actually there are optimizations, that are performed in the frontend, but probably they are not so important.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: my experience has been that if there is no output, gfortran-compiled code does not actually run (constant 0.001 second run-times).

Comment: Ah yes, good point, a sensible optimiser will create an empty `main()`

Comment: Should be `for (unsigned int k=1; k<=10000000; ++k)` to have the same loop as the fortran version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time differences will be related to the time it takes to execute `pow`, as the other code is relatively simple. You can check this by profiling. The question then is what the compiler does to compute the power function?

My timings: ~1.20 s for the Fortran version with `gfortran -O3`, and 1.07 s for the C++ version compiled with `g++ -O3 -ffast-math`. Note that `-ffast-math` doesn't matter for `gfortran`, as `pow` will be called from a library, but it makes a huge difference for `g++`.

In my case, for `gfortran`, it's the function `_gfortran_pow_c8_i4` that gets called ([source code](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libgfortran/generated/pow_c8_i4.c?view=markup)). Their implementation is the usual way to compute integer powers. With `g++` on the other hand, it's a function template from the libstdc++ library, but I don't know how that's implemented. Apparently, it's slightly better written/optimizable. I don't know to what extent the function is compiled on the fly, considering it's a template. For what it's worth, the Fortran version compiled with `ifort` and C++ version compiled with `icc` (using `-fast` optimization flag) both give the same timings, so I guess these use the same library functions.

If I just write a power function in Fortran with complex arithmetic (explicitely writing out real and imaginary parts), it's as fast as the C++ version compiled with `g++` (but then `-ffast-math` slows it down, so I stuck to only `-O3` with `gfortran`):

```
complex(8) function pow_c8_i4(a, k)
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: k
complex(8), intent(in) :: a

real(8) :: Re_a, Im_a, Re_pow, Im_pow, tmp
integer :: i

Re_pow = 1.0_8
Im_pow = 0.0_8
Re_a = real(a)
Im_a = aimag(a)
i = k

do while (i.ne.0)
  if (iand(i,1).eq.1) then
    tmp = Re_pow
    Re_pow = Re_pow*Re_a-Im_pow*Im_a
    Im_pow = tmp   *Im_a+Im_pow*Re_a
  end if
  i = ishft(i,-1)
  tmp = Re_a
  Re_a = Re_a**2-Im_a**2
  Im_a = 2*tmp*Im_a
end do
pow_c8_i4 = cmplx(Re_pow,Im_pow,8)
end function
```

In my experience, using explicit real and imaginary parts in Fortran implementations is faster, allthough it's very convenient of course to use the complex types.

Final note: even though it's just an example, the way to call the power function each iteration is extremely inefficient.  Instead, you should of course just multiply `a` by itself each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is in the output part. It is well-known that C++ streams (`std::cout`) are often very inefficient. While different compilers may optimize this, it is always a good idea to rewrite critical performance parts using C `printf` function instead of `std::cout`.

Comment: I don't think 10 printouts are going to affect performance in the ~1.0 s range.

Comment: You may be right. I did not test it myself, but that is definitely the think one should always look at.